# How to send the notification on every task execution in a state machine on AW step functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, aws-step-functions

I am working on Amazon Step functions to leverage the workflow for multiple Batch jobs. The requirement is such that the Batch jobs should be executed sequentially and whenever a job transition from one to another job then send a notification with the execution status of the tasks to a SNS topic. **I need to send a notification for SUCCESS and FAILURE of a task.**

I have tried the Execution Events using Cloudwatch event rules, but Execution Events only gives information about the State Machine's execution, not about the Tasks execution.

Answer (score 0):

As you have found states aren't in Cloudwatch events need to add this as a separate step, there is no way around this, have a notify step which either executes a lambda, or `sync` to SNS.

There is also another way to do this as you can compose step functions of step functions. So you have your parent step function and your child step function. Your child step function could be the batch job itself, and then you can make use of Cloudwatch events on the `batch-job-step-function` step function:

```
"BatchJob" : {
      "Comment": "This snippet is in the parent step function. It will kick off another step function, called: batch-job-step-function",
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "StateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:TODO:stateMachine:batch-job-step-function",
        "Input": {
          "batchJobInput.$": "$$.Execution.Input.batchJobInput"
        }
      },
      "End": true | "Next" : "TODO"
    }
```

Now you can put Cloudwatch Event Rules against: `arn:aws:states:us-east-1:TODO:stateMachine:batch-job-step-function`

Comment: As per the Amazon state language guide, you cannot have "End" and "Next" together in the same task which is why I was not able to have it in the same task.

Comment: This is just an example, use `End` if your batch job is your last task, otherwise use `Next` to go to your next task in your step function.